Split array of objects into multidimensional array using property to group items
I’ve got an array of objects that each carry a columnSpan property with a numeric value between 1 and 16.
[
  {
    "columnSpan": 4,
    "id": "DatoCmsEntry-MaixsOYtSwS7mloD59Rvng"
  },
  {
    "columnSpan": 4,
    "id": "DatoCmsEntry-fEuNly9-QFiRh4DoUZ-Y_w"
  },
  {
    "columnSpan": 2,
    "id": "DatoCmsEntry-HsAgXDMHQkSXS_4lKSGfGA"
  },
  {
    "columnSpan": 2,
    "id": "DatoCmsEntry-BM-fSBruSM67IFzCrBSLBg"
  },
  {
    "columnSpan": 3,
    "id": "DatoCmsEntry-JPushhKGSBCwR_uWcwIFSw"
  },
  {
    "columnSpan": 3,
    "id": "DatoCmsEntry-Q0sfjP9ZQZSDZZVP_sI9ew"
  },
  {
    "columnSpan": 2,
    "id": "DatoCmsEntry-CdVhbQENQ4ib2z4w3wc20Q"
  },
  {
    "columnSpan": 2,
    "id": "DatoCmsEntry-Fn2U_0CuQDiBEOZLmS3ovQ"
  }
]

I need to split this array up into a multidimensional array where each top-level item represents a collection of records where the total columnSpan is 16 or less, keeping the original order, like this:
[
  [
    {
      "columnSpan": 4,
      "id": "DatoCmsEntry-MaixsOYtSwS7mloD59Rvng"
    },
    {
      "columnSpan": 4,
      "id": "DatoCmsEntry-fEuNly9-QFiRh4DoUZ-Y_w"
    },
    {
      "columnSpan": 2,
      "id": "DatoCmsEntry-HsAgXDMHQkSXS_4lKSGfGA"
    },
    {
      "columnSpan": 2,
      "id": "DatoCmsEntry-BM-fSBruSM67IFzCrBSLBg"
    },
    {
      "columnSpan": 3,
      "id": "DatoCmsEntry-JPushhKGSBCwR_uWcwIFSw"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "columnSpan": 3,
      "id": "DatoCmsEntry-Q0sfjP9ZQZSDZZVP_sI9ew"
    },
    {
      "columnSpan": 2,
      "id": "DatoCmsEntry-CdVhbQENQ4ib2z4w3wc20Q"
    },
    {
      "columnSpan": 2,
      "id": "DatoCmsEntry-Fn2U_0CuQDiBEOZLmS3ovQ"
    }
  ]
]

Suggestions on ways to pull this off?

also: Split array into chunks of a total value or How to create array chunk based on property value

Also show what you have tried and what isn't working.

Reduce the array. In the reducer start by checking if a new chunk should be added. Always add the current item to the last chunk.


const fn = (arr, max) => arr.reduce((acc, o) => {
  // add a new chunk and reset sum if no chunks, or next item would go over the max
  if(!acc.res.length || acc.sum + o.columnSpan > max) {
    acc.sum = 0
    acc.res.push([])
  }

  acc.res.at(-1).push(o) // push current item to last chunk

  acc.sum += o.columnSpan // add current columnSpan to sum

  return acc
}, { res: [], sum: 0 }).res

const data = [{"columnSpan":4,"id":"DatoCmsEntry-MaixsOYtSwS7mloD59Rvng"},{"columnSpan":4,"id":"DatoCmsEntry-fEuNly9-QFiRh4DoUZ-Y_w"},{"columnSpan":2,"id":"DatoCmsEntry-HsAgXDMHQkSXS_4lKSGfGA"},{"columnSpan":2,"id":"DatoCmsEntry-BM-fSBruSM67IFzCrBSLBg"},{"columnSpan":3,"id":"DatoCmsEntry-JPushhKGSBCwR_uWcwIFSw"},{"columnSpan":3,"id":"DatoCmsEntry-Q0sfjP9ZQZSDZZVP_sI9ew"},{"columnSpan":2,"id":"DatoCmsEntry-CdVhbQENQ4ib2z4w3wc20Q"},{"columnSpan":2,"id":"DatoCmsEntry-Fn2U_0CuQDiBEOZLmS3ovQ"}]

const result = fn(data, 16)

console.log(result)




you can pull this off by keeping 2 extra variables to track the current chunk and the current total. Anyway you need an array to store the chunks. Then it is just a loop. I keep adding to the current chunk until it is less than or equal to 16, else I'm resetting the current chunked and total variables. Also I directly do currentChunk = [item] currentTotal = item.columnSpan instead of currentChunk = [] & currentChunk.push(item) and currentTotal = 0 & currentTotal += item.columnSpan
The final if check is needed to add the final chunk


const data  = [ { "columnSpan": 4, "id": "DatoCmsEntry-MaixsOYtSwS7mloD59Rvng" }, { "columnSpan": 4, "id": "DatoCmsEntry-fEuNly9-QFiRh4DoUZ-Y_w" }, { "columnSpan": 2, "id": "DatoCmsEntry-HsAgXDMHQkSXS_4lKSGfGA" }, { "columnSpan": 2, "id": "DatoCmsEntry-BM-fSBruSM67IFzCrBSLBg" }, { "columnSpan": 3, "id": "DatoCmsEntry-JPushhKGSBCwR_uWcwIFSw" }, { "columnSpan": 3, "id": "DatoCmsEntry-Q0sfjP9ZQZSDZZVP_sI9ew" }, { "columnSpan": 2, "id": "DatoCmsEntry-CdVhbQENQ4ib2z4w3wc20Q" }, { "columnSpan": 2, "id": "DatoCmsEntry-Fn2U_0CuQDiBEOZLmS3ovQ" } ]

const chunked = []
let currentChunk = []
let currentTotal = 0

for (const item of data) {
  if (currentTotal + item.columnSpan <= 16) {
    currentChunk.push(item)
    currentTotal += item.columnSpan
  } else {
    chunked.push(currentChunk)
    currentChunk = [item]
    currentTotal = item.columnSpan
  }
}

if (currentChunk.length > 0) {
  chunked.push(currentChunk)
}

console.log(chunked)



or same thing using a reduce


const data  = [ { "columnSpan": 4, "id": "DatoCmsEntry-MaixsOYtSwS7mloD59Rvng" }, { "columnSpan": 4, "id": "DatoCmsEntry-fEuNly9-QFiRh4DoUZ-Y_w" }, { "columnSpan": 2, "id": "DatoCmsEntry-HsAgXDMHQkSXS_4lKSGfGA" }, { "columnSpan": 2, "id": "DatoCmsEntry-BM-fSBruSM67IFzCrBSLBg" }, { "columnSpan": 3, "id": "DatoCmsEntry-JPushhKGSBCwR_uWcwIFSw" }, { "columnSpan": 3, "id": "DatoCmsEntry-Q0sfjP9ZQZSDZZVP_sI9ew" }, { "columnSpan": 2, "id": "DatoCmsEntry-CdVhbQENQ4ib2z4w3wc20Q" }, { "columnSpan": 2, "id": "DatoCmsEntry-Fn2U_0CuQDiBEOZLmS3ovQ" } ]

const {chunked, currentChunk} = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (acc.currentTotal + curr.columnSpan <= 16) {
    acc.currentChunk.push(curr)
    acc.currentTotal += curr.columnSpan
  } else {
    acc.chunked.push(acc.currentChunk)
    acc.currentChunk = [curr]
    acc.currentTotal = curr.columnSpan
  }
  return acc
}, { chunked: [], currentChunk: [], currentTotal: 0 })

if (currentChunk.length) {
  chunked.push(currentChunk)
}

console.log(chunked)




I will suggest an option with the use of reduce. The script goes sequentially through the array and counts ColumnSpan. If no more than 16, it adds to the current array, if it exceeds, it adds to the next one, and so on.


const init = [
  {"columnSpan": 4, "id": "DatoCmsEntry-MaixsOYtSwS7mloD59Rvng"},
  {"columnSpan": 4, "id": "DatoCmsEntry-fEuNly9-QFiRh4DoUZ-Y_w"},
  {"columnSpan": 2, "id": "DatoCmsEntry-HsAgXDMHQkSXS_4lKSGfGA"},
  {"columnSpan": 2, "id": "DatoCmsEntry-BM-fSBruSM67IFzCrBSLBg"},
  {"columnSpan": 3, "id": "DatoCmsEntry-JPushhKGSBCwR_uWcwIFSw"},
  {"columnSpan": 3, "id": "DatoCmsEntry-Q0sfjP9ZQZSDZZVP_sI9ew"},
  {"columnSpan": 2, "id": "DatoCmsEntry-CdVhbQENQ4ib2z4w3wc20Q"},
  {"columnSpan": 2, "id": "DatoCmsEntry-Fn2U_0CuQDiBEOZLmS3ovQ"},
  {"columnSpan": 4, "id": "DatoCmsEntry-Fn2U_0CuQDiBEOZLmS3ovQ"},
  {"columnSpan": 5, "id": "DatoCmsEntry-Fn2U_0CuQDiBEOZLmS3ovQ"},
  {"columnSpan": 8, "id": "DatoCmsEntry-Fn2U_0CuQDiBEOZLmS3ovQ"},
  {"columnSpan": 8, "id": "DatoCmsEntry-Fn2U_0CuQDiBEOZLmS3ovQ"},
];

function groupBySum(init) {
  const group = init.reduce((acc, item) => {
    const summa = acc.sum + item.columnSpan;
    if (summa <= 16) {
      acc.delta.push(item);
      acc.sum = summa;
    } else {
      acc.sum = item.columnSpan;
      acc.result.push(acc.delta);
      acc.delta = [];
      acc.delta.push(item)
    }
    return acc;
  }, { sum: 0, result: [], delta: []});

  group.result.push(group.delta);

  return group.result;
}

console.log(groupBySum(init))



OR


const init = [
  {"columnSpan": 4, "id": "DatoCmsEntry-MaixsOYtSwS7mloD59Rvng"},
  {"columnSpan": 4, "id": "DatoCmsEntry-fEuNly9-QFiRh4DoUZ-Y_w"},
  {"columnSpan": 2, "id": "DatoCmsEntry-HsAgXDMHQkSXS_4lKSGfGA"},
  {"columnSpan": 2, "id": "DatoCmsEntry-BM-fSBruSM67IFzCrBSLBg"},
  {"columnSpan": 3, "id": "DatoCmsEntry-JPushhKGSBCwR_uWcwIFSw"},
  {"columnSpan": 3, "id": "DatoCmsEntry-Q0sfjP9ZQZSDZZVP_sI9ew"},
  {"columnSpan": 2, "id": "DatoCmsEntry-CdVhbQENQ4ib2z4w3wc20Q"},
  {"columnSpan": 2, "id": "DatoCmsEntry-Fn2U_0CuQDiBEOZLmS3ovQ"},
  {"columnSpan": 4, "id": "DatoCmsEntry-Fn2U_0CuQDiBEOZLmS3ovQ"},
  {"columnSpan": 5, "id": "DatoCmsEntry-Fn2U_0CuQDiBEOZLmS3ovQ"},
  {"columnSpan": 8, "id": "DatoCmsEntry-Fn2U_0CuQDiBEOZLmS3ovQ"},
  {"columnSpan": 8, "id": "DatoCmsEntry-Fn2U_0CuQDiBEOZLmS3ovQ"},
];

function splitBySpan(arr) {
  let acc = 0;
  let slot = 0;
  const result = [[]];
  arr.forEach(item => {
    if (acc + item.columnSpan <= 16) {
      acc += item.columnSpan;
      result[slot].push(item);
    } else {
      acc = item.columnSpan;
      slot++;
      result.push([item])
    }
  })
  return result;
}
console.log(splitBySpan(init));



